# Adding cells in an array/vector based on criteria - Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, addition

I have a data vector `448X2` where the first column corresponds to distances (from -50 to 224) and the second column contains the intensity associate with each distance.

I need to add all the intensities that are with in distance regardless of direction (positive/negative). For example, I want to add intervals of 1. So, if have 5 values within [-1 1] distance range I need to add all their intensities. Then, from [-2 -1] & [1 2] distance, etc, etc, ...

I started by shorting the data from 0 to 224

```
datasort = sortrows(abs(data));
```

which takes cake of the negative numbers. Now that my data is sorted by distance in increasing order I don't know how to add the intensities within a distance interval.

These are the first 10 rows of my `datasort` vector:

```
0.119865417480469   0.0115106217563152
0.669918060302734   0.356697350740433
0.909893035888672   0.659623980522156
1.45951080322266    1.69302666187286
1.70020294189453    2.30387997627258
2.24539566040039    3.98834538459778
2.49082183837891    4.94714736938477
3.02403259277344    7.16749382019043
3.28177261352539    8.59203147888184
3.79549789428711    11.1872768402100
```

I want to end up with something like this:

```
1   1.02780000000000
2   3.99690000000000
3   8.93550000000000
4   26.9468000000000
```

where the first colums now contains discrete distance values from 1-224 (`1:224`) and the second column the sum of all the intensities for the distance range.

I hope I was clear enough. Thanks

update:

I figured I can do:

```
datasort(:,1) = round(datasort(:,1));
```

Which gives me (first 10 points),

```
0   0.0115106217563152
1   0.356697350740433
1   0.659623980522156
1   1.69302666187286
2   2.30387997627258
2   3.98834538459778
2   4.94714736938477
3   7.16749382019043
3   8.59203147888184
4   11.1872768402100
```

I still don't know how add the intensities with the same distance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first use `histc` in order to bin the first column of your data and then pass along the indices that `histc` returns to `accumarray` operating on the second column. Note you shouldn't even need to sort your data to do this, although you still need to call `abs` in order to remove the negative numbers.

```
>> data = [0.119865417480469   0.0115106217563152
0.669918060302734   0.356697350740433
0.909893035888672   0.659623980522156
1.45951080322266    1.69302666187286
1.70020294189453    2.30387997627258
2.24539566040039    3.98834538459778
2.49082183837891    4.94714736938477
3.02403259277344    7.16749382019043
3.28177261352539    8.59203147888184
3.79549789428711    11.1872768402100]

data =

         0.119865417480469        0.0115106217563152
         0.669918060302734         0.356697350740433
         0.909893035888672         0.659623980522156
          1.45951080322266          1.69302666187286
          1.70020294189453          2.30387997627258
          2.24539566040039          3.98834538459778
          2.49082183837891          4.94714736938477
          3.02403259277344          7.16749382019043
          3.28177261352539          8.59203147888184
          3.79549789428711            11.18727684021

>> [~, idx] = histc(data(:,1), [0:224]) 

idx =

     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
     3
     3
     4
     4
     4

>> result = accumarray(idx, data(:,2))

result =

           1.0278319530189
          3.99690663814544
          8.93549275398255
          26.9468021392823

>>
```

Hope that helps!

EDIT:

Just to confirm this does indeed work without sorting your data

```
>> % Unsort your data snippet to illustrate
>> data = data([randperm(length(data))],:)

data =

          3.79549789428711            11.18727684021
          1.45951080322266          1.69302666187286
         0.909893035888672         0.659623980522156
          2.24539566040039          3.98834538459778
          1.70020294189453          2.30387997627258
         0.119865417480469        0.0115106217563152
         0.669918060302734         0.356697350740433
          3.28177261352539          8.59203147888184
          3.02403259277344          7.16749382019043
          2.49082183837891          4.94714736938477

>> [~, idx] = histc(data(:,1), [0:224])

idx =

     4
     2
     1
     3
     2
     1
     1
     4
     4
     3

>> result = accumarray(idx, data(:,2))

result =

           1.0278319530189
          3.99690663814544
          8.93549275398255
          26.9468021392823

>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
datasort = sortrows(abs(data));
datasort(:,1) = 1+floor(datasort(:,1));
inSum=zeros(1,max(datasort(:,1)));
for i=1:max(datasort(:,1))
    inSum(i)=sum(datasort(i==datasort(:,1),2));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical indexing to extract those rows from your matrix and then sum up column 2.

```
m = floor(min(x(:,1)));
M = floor(max(x(:,1)));
for i = m:M 
   sum(x(x(:,1)=>i & x(:,1)<=i+1, 2));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) can do that in one line:

```
result = accumarray(ceil(datasort(:,1)), datasort(:,2));
```